# How to add a ScrollBar in JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx, scrollbar

I'm trying to add a ScrollBar to a HBox. The ScrollBar gets added, but I get no scrolling. How can I make it work?

```
public class ScrollableItems {

    public void scrollableItems(HBox content) {

        double height = 180;

        ScrollBar sc = new ScrollBar();

        content.getChildren().add(sc);

        sc.setLayoutX(content.getWidth() - sc.getWidth());
        sc.setMin(0);
        sc.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
        sc.setPrefHeight(height);
        sc.setMax(height * 2);

        sc.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov,
                    Number old_val, Number new_val) {
                content.setLayoutY(-new_val.doubleValue());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Add children to a HBox then pass it to `scrollableItems(HBox content)` above to add a SCrollBar

```
public HBox mainItemsWrapper() {
    HBox scrollabelWrapper = new HBox();
    scrollabelWrapper.setMaxHeight(180);

    HBox entityDetailViewWrapper = new HBox();

    entityDetailViewWrapper.getChildren().addAll(.....);

    scrollabelWrapper.getChildren().add(entityDetailViewWrapper);
    new ScrollableItems().scrollableItems(scrollabelWrapper);

    return scrollabelWrapper;
}
```

Thank you all.....

Answer (score 13):

I do not really get why you are trying to reinvent the wheel.. you should probably use the [`ScrollPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html) instead.

This little example shows how to create a horizontally scrollable HBox with the `ScrollPane` class:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    HBox hbox = new HBox();

    Button b = new Button("add");
    b.setOnAction(ev -> hbox.getChildren().add(new Label("Test")));

    ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(hbox);
    scrollPane.setFitToHeight(true);

    BorderPane root = new BorderPane(scrollPane);
    root.setPadding(new Insets(15));
    root.setTop(b);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @eckig. Is there a way I can catch the ScrollPane's ScrollBar and customize its width?

Comment: Did you try setting the width of the `ScrollPane` itself? That should work.

Answer (score 4):

As eckig said, you can wrap you HBox into a [ScrollPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html).

Additionnaly, you can customize the visual part of the scrollbar in CSS. I found this link useful for the comprehension of the differents parts of a scrollbar: [Customize ScrollBar via CSS](http://blog.ngopal.com.np/2012/07/11/customize-scrollbar-via-css/)